# Symfony 5 Rest, Base64 encoded file to DTO with validation as File object

Tags: rest, file, symfony, base64, dto

I have a `PostController` looking like this:

```
 #[Route(name: 'add', methods: ['POST'])]
 public function addPost(Request $request): JsonResponse
 {
    /** @var PostRequestDto $postRequest */
    $postRequest = $this->serializer->deserialize(
        $request->getContent(),
        PostRequestDto::class,
        'json'
    );

    return $this->postService->addPost($postRequest);
}
```

`PostService`:

```
public function addPost(PostRequestDto $request): JsonResponse
{
    $errors = $this->validator->validate($request);
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        throw new ValidationHttpException($errors);
    }

    #...

    return new JsonResponse(null, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

And `PostRequestDto`:

```
class PostRequestDto
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 250)]
    private ?string $title;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 1000)]
    private ?string $article;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Image]
    private ?File $photo;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual('now', message: 'post_request_dto.publish_date.greater_than_or_equal')]
    private ?DateTimeInterface $publishDate;
}
```

My Postman request looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "Test",
    "article": "lorem ipsum....",
    "photo": "base64...",
    "publishDate": "2021-10-15 08:00:00"
}
```

As you can see from postman request, I'm sending `base64` encoded file.
Now, in the controller I want to deserialize it to match with `PostRequestDto` so I can validate it as a `File` in the `PostService` - how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly your serializer (`$this->serializer`) is configured, but I think you have to adjust/add your normilizer with `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DataUriNormalizer`

```php
// somewhere in your controller/service where serilaizer is configured/set
$normalizers = [
   //... your other normilizers if any
   new DataUriNormalizer(), // this one
   ];
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];

$this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```

If you look inside `DataUriNormalizer` you'll see, it works with `File` which is exactly what you have in your `PostRequestDto`

The only thing to be aware of → format of base64.
If you follow the [link](https://gist.github.com/bgrins/6194623) of `denormilize()` method, you will see it expects `data:image/png;base64,...`
So it has to start with `data:...` and you probably have to change your postman-json-payload to

```json
{
    "title": "Test",
    "article": "lorem ipsum....",
    "photo": "data:<your_base64_string>",
    "publishDate": "2021-10-15 08:00:00"
}
```

Since you work with images, I would also send the mime-type. Like:

```json
"photo": "data:image/png;base64,<your_base64_string>",
```

Comment: My serializer is injected into the constructor with `PostService` like this: 
`public function __construct(private SerializerInterface $serializer, private PostService $postService)` - after using the `DataUriNormalizer()` I'm getting `File could not be found` error... Any ideas why that happened ?

Comment: I think your json-payload contains only base_64 string representation of image contents. Try to `dd($postRequest);` right after deserialization. 
You will notice, that `File` have no information about path. You have to do it manually... it depends on your business logic. Either in a database as a blob or somewhere on disk.

Comment: It looks like this: `"photo": "data:image/jpeg;base64,<base64_string>"`

Comment: @Slimu I don't know how your `PostService` manages and/or stores images. Maybe you could reveal more file related logic from your `PostService::addPost()` method.

Comment: Well, the problem was with storing the image, thanks for help